# Get list of physical paths of all websites on IIS

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7

I have been asked to get involved server migration task . I have been given task to get list of physical paths of all websites hosted on **IIS** .

I know how to get individual websites path in **IIS** using GUI and also able to view list of websites and corresponding physical path in **IIS** GUI by clicking on **View Application** link.

But I dont know how to export this info to Excel sheet.

Is there any option in GUI or some command to be executed in **command prompt** which will help retrieve the required information in one go ?

There are many websites hosted and it would be cumbersome to visit each application , copy physical paths and paste into excel.

Answer (score 1):

> APPCMD LIST VDIRS

And anything which ends with a slash is a site (a root level application).

**But that'd be doing it wrong!**

Any server migration which doesn't involve the use of Web Deployment Tool (MSDeploy) to pretty-much-automatically:

- package up all the websites and the content,
- and blat it onto the target system

is likely to be a waste of your time, longer term.

Go get WebDeploy, have a muck around with it, and use it for the migration.

Out:
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:webserver60 -dest:package=c:\webServer.zip

or any variation on that. In is basically just the same, with reversed source and dest arguments.

http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/use-the-web-deployment-tool